# SQL Sum values in table when it encounters a specific conditions

Tags: sql, case, sybase, aggregation

I would like to sum the result set from a table when it matches a conditions

Suppose, the table  contains below data

```
ID PILLER AMOUNT
1  1M     10000
2  2M     15000
3  1M     10000
4  3W     50000
5  1M     10000
```

Now, from the table rows I would like to sum the amount of 1M which appears 3 time  to one row.

Comment: given the 5 sample rows, provide the final result you'd expect to see; are you looking for a single row in the final result or 3 rows (2W+3W+1M, 2M, 1W)? what columns are you looking to display in the final result set (eg, what should show up under the 'PILLER' column for the combined rows)?

Comment: Final result would be
ID PILLER AMOUNT
1  1M     30000
2  2M     15000
4  3W     50000

Comment: edit/update your question to include the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?
In case there are multiple pillars associated to an id

```
 Select 
 ID,PILLER,Sum(AMOUNT) 
 from table where piller 
 in ('2W','3W','1M') 
 group 
 by ID,PILLAR ;
```

or only pillarwise sum

```
  Select 
  PILLER,Sum(AMOUNT) 
 from table where piller 
 in ('2W','3W','1M') 
 group 
 by PILLAR ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `in` operator in where clause

```
   select sum(amount) from table
    where piller in ('2W','3W','1M')
```